# Issue while scrolling to UITableView bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a chat application ,where in when I press the send button the table gets reloaded with new row and I am calling scroll to bottom function to scroll to the newly added cell. The problem is that my textview text does not get emptied until the tableview scrolls to the bottom. Is there any other way to perform these actions so as to reduce the time delay?

Scroll to botton code:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
let section: Int = numberOfSections(in: self.tableView) - 1
let item: Int = tableView(self.tableView, numberOfRowsInSection:section) - 1
let lastIndexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: lastIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
```

When I remove the above code, the textview gets emptied instantly

The issue :

[image]

Comment: You should reload the table asynchronously. I think that will prevent other issues. Use this: `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }`

Comment: You can hide the text view first, then reload and scroll to bottom, then empty the text view and unhide it.

Comment: I am emptying the textview before scrolltobottom is executed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you call reloadData() on the main thread. Doing it in a background thread will often cause graphical delays and may even crash the application.

Also, where do you empty the textview?

Comment: I empty it before scrolltobottom is called